# Eclipse juno color theme bug under linux?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have installed the Eclipse Color Theme 0.12.0. I noticed when I double click a variable and then click off it had a gray highlight left behind. I cant seen to find a setting to fix this.

Running on Fedora Linux (15) with no sudo rights.

Is there a setting for this?

[image: eclipse juno bug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check window -> preferences -> editors -> text editors -> annotations -> occurrences.

That will allow you to change whether or not other occurrences of a variable/etc. get highlighted.

Also, another place to look is

Window -> preferences -> C/C++ -> editor -> mark occurrences (this also has a link to the above place).

Unchecking that selection should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give this ago tomorrow when I be on the machines (uni).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse highlights all occurrences of the symbol. You need to change the background for that case - unfortunately Eclipse has a **lot** of places where colors are defined, so you'll need a bit of experimenting to find where the background for the "highlighted symbol" - or how it's called - is defined.

P.S. Also, I tried Color Theme few times and it was very buggy. But not with Juno.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give this ago tomorrow when I be on the machines (uni).